# Unable to connect my ohp application to Openldap server with ldap_connect() , return ressource id#2

Tags: php, ubuntu, openldap, phpldapadmin

I'v installed Openldap in Ubuntu 14.04 and i'v also installed phpldapadmin everything looks fine until this step , but when i try to connect my php application with this script i have the same response as a result resource id #2

this is my script :

```
$ds=ldap_connect("ladp://192.168.1.2",389)or die("Could not connect to $ldaphost");  

echo 'Le résultat de connexion est ' . $ds . '<br />';

if ($ds) { 
echo 'Liaison ...'; 
$username = "cn=admin,dc=ldap,dc=com";
$upasswd = "password";
$r=ldap_bind($ds,$username, $upasswd);    
echo 'Le résultat de connexion est ' . $r . '<br />';
```

Comment: Is it as simple as `ladp:` =/= `ldap:` , Minor typo

Comment: What were you expecting? ldap_bind() is equivalent to mysql[i]_connect() in that it establishes a connection to a service (but requires the resource created by ldap_connect() as an argument - ldap_connect() doesn't actually connect). If its returning a resource id, then its successful. You still need to send a query to get some data back.

Comment: yes i know that it doesn not actually connect but the variable $ds return always resource id#2 even if i enter an invalide host

Comment: @RiggsFolly i'v changed it to ldap but still the same response

Comment: @RiggsFolly when i execute the code it shows me 'Liaison...' but when it comes to ldap_bind it doesn't work

Comment: See my answer, refresh page first, I just finished editing it. echo out the error, that may help you fix whatever is wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LDAP 2

> When OpenLDAP 2.x.x is used, ldap_connect() will always return a resource as it does not actually connect but just initializes the connecting parameters. The actual connect happens with the next calls to ldap_* funcs, usually with ldap_bind().

I think you might need to test the result of the `ldap_bind()` like this suggestion [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php)

```
<?php

    $ds=ldap_connect("ldap://192.168.1.2",389)or die("Could not connect to $ldaphost");  

    $username = "cn=admin,dc=ldap,dc=com";
    $upasswd = "password";
    $r=ldap_bind($ds,$username, $upasswd);  
    // verify binding
    if ($r) {
        echo 'Le résultat de connexion est ' . $r . '<br />';
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...\n";
        echo ldap_error($ds);
    }
```

Comment: You are not using my answer code then. REFRESH The page `CTRL+F5` you may be seeing a previous edit. My code does not have that line in it

Comment: when i tried it with your code it's shows nothing i thinks tha variable $r is null

Comment: If `$r` is NULL then it should print `LDAP bind failed...` and the ldap_error message.

Comment: Sorry I copied the `ladp` error into my code and forgot to fix it, try again

Comment: still have the same response i changed ladp to ldap but it shows me nothing